PayPal checkout does not work for funding services
I created a simple website with PayPal checkout integrated on client side in order to collect some fees for accesing my mobile app. It works great except for funding services like BLIK, iDEAL, Przelewy24 etc - basically third party payment services. It works in sandbox but whenever someone tries to purchase using funding services whole payment completes on funding service side but I cannot see any payment on my PayPal account. Effect is customer spend money and I dont get it..
When I check my API call history on PayPal account there is 'POST /v2/checkout/orders' registerd but there is no corresponding 'POST /v2/checkout/orders/.../capture' event registered - I suppose this captures the payment on PayPal side. I was trying to get PayPal support but it takes ages and most likely the issue is related to the way I set up the payment.
Could anyone take a look on  the way I implemented it and let me know if I shall correct the code:
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AU8GOhxtmtuzCdJ6wfp0FqG-UOLoEmKbShePWUw8MoCO1cGl1EWw9SdSD93EcAlAMbTrOC9MDuXl3Mec&currency=EUR"></script>
<script>

      var selectedApp = null;
      var inputEmail = null;
      var inputCode = null;
      var purchasePrice = 9.99.toString();
      var purchaseStatus = false;

      paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [
                    {
                        description: selectedApp + ' ' + inputEmail + ' ' + inputCode,
                        amount: {
                            currency_code: 'EUR',
                            value: purchasePrice,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            })
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';

            })
        }
      }).render("#paypal")

  </script>

(the global variables are set up using a form on the payment website)

Those alternative funding services can sometimes complete payments without a /capture call occurring, since they send the buyer away from both your site and PayPal. The money should still appear in your PayPal account, however. As for being notified, you can subscribe to webhooks using the the REST APP/Client ID you are integrated with, there will be one for the capture being completed.

Not directly related to your problem, but actions.order.create( and actions.order.capture( are deprecated functions. PayPal has begun sending communications that this client-side-only pattern will be sunset and processing switched off, do not use it. Instead, create and capture orders from a secured server by having it directly integrate with the v2/checkout/orders API. See the standard integration guide, its backend samples are in node.js but any environment (Java, PHP, .NET, whatever) can implement those routes and their API calls to PayPal.

Ok so I basically copy paste the client/server code shown on standard integration guide video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBfJEUGNNs0&t  |  https://github.com/paypaldev/PayPal-Standard-Checkout-Tutorial) but with my credentials and unfortunately it still does not work for funding services. The  paypal checkout which I tested is temporarily available here: http://16.171.28.140:3000/ - I would appreciate if you could give me a helping hand to make it work.

Seems okay. Is the capture route being called in live mode for alternative funding sources, or not? If no capture is done, the customer's payment will be returned.  You can listen for order approved webhooks as a failsafe but it shouldn't be necessary in general.

That is the problem, the order is not captured. The order can be found in API call list but it is not subsequently captured.  Paypal support told me this is due to funding service not POSTing the capture order. How am I suppose to force them to do it?!... I must be missing something but still pending some feedback from paypal. The problem is I'm missing almost half of my income based on number of calls I can see. Any ideas how to proceed?

So, what is happening in live mode when using these funding methods? You've tested it, right? The client code onApprove should be triggered, it should fetch from your backend, your backend should do a v2/checkout/orders capture API call, that API call should return a completed order with a PayPal transaction ID in its details. Exactly which of those is and which of those is not happening?  Apparently in sandbox it all works, so you need to be precise about what is not working in live.

I've just checked and  after payment is completed on third party service side, money are taken from my bank account, third party service gives me a message that payment was completed and it was transferred to the seler, I get email confirmations (btw my customers reported me the samebehavior for different funding services eg. iDEAL or Przelewy24) and THEN no onApprove is triggered.. instead onCancel is happening.

All that is normal except of course the part where onCancel is called instead of onApprove. Strip your example down to be as close to https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server as possible; no event listeners or other dynamic JS stuff. Keep it dirt simple. And work on adding a webhook listener to do the capture as a fallback since even when everything is working as well as it can these third party funding source won't always trigger onApprove successfully, various things always have some chance of interrupting that.

A further possibility: from onCancel you can perhaps attempt the capture anyway, if it works treat the same as onApprove from then on

Hmm nice trick, I would check on my money before moving to prod. In paralel i will ask directly Przelewy24 support why those transactions are processed that way.

Other than figuring out why onCancel is being triggered instead of onApprove (which is between PayPal and Przelewy24 I guess), I don't see an issue for Przelewy24 support here. Working as designed.
